# Normalization where the smallest grid value gets the biggest value with “rescale by function”

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, normalize

I tried to normalize a density analysis between 0 and 100 with the tool “rescale by function”. The tricky thing is now, that the smallest value out of the density analysis should get the value 100 (here: 0) and the biggest value should get the value 0 (here: 5.28). I used the tool “rescale by function”, as shown below. 
[image]
But I am struggling with the result, because the lowest grid value is negative, but it should be 0 (null). Does anyone have a solution for this problem? The result grid should have the values 0 – 100, where 100 was the smallest value from the density analysis and 0 the biggest value from the density output grid. 
I am working with ArcGIS 10.6.

Comment: Did you try to convert your raster after to int raster?

Comment: I am not tracking here, are you also trying to invert the values?

Comment: Thanks for answering, using the tool „Int“  after the tool “rescale by function” gave the desired result. 
However, I am wondering if the result, that is calculated, now is right, as I want to also invert the values what Jeffry Evans asked.

Comment: This tool will not invert your values as that is an entirely different statistical function. Scale your data to the desired range and then apply a method that inverts the raster values. There is a tool available for this in the Gradient Metrics Toolbox (https://github.com/jeffreyevans/GradientMetrics).